# PHP include relative path

Tags: php

I have file  /root/update/test.php. There's also a file, /root/connect.php; This file has a line

```
include "../config.php";
```

In /root/update/test.php. There's the code

```
set_include_path(".:/root");
include "connect.php";
```

When I run /root/update/test.php, it finds connect.php, but fails to find config.php, giving me

```
PHP Warning:  include(../config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /root/connect.php on line 2
PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '../config.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/root')
```

This is confusing to me because the warnings make it seem like I'm doing everything correctly - the include path is /root, and it's looking for file ../config.php (/config.php), which exists. Can someone clear this up for me? Note that using absolute paths is not an option for me, due to deploying to a production server that I have no access to.

Ubuntu/Apache

Comment: I tries to include config.php relative to your CWD, which is /root/update/, and searches for /root/config.php

Comment: This: include "../config.php" takes you to the folder that is parent to root folder. Is config.php situated there?

Comment: What is the full path of config.php?

Comment: yep, the absolute path is /config.php

Comment: Use this for your first line: include "config.php"; because connect.php is in root also.

Comment: personally I would change all file references to be absolute e.g. include realpath(\__DIR\__ . '/../') . '/config.php';

Comment: @kevin - that's what I ended up doing, good suggestion, thanks

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 161, accepted):

You could always include it using `__DIR__`:

```
include(dirname(__DIR__).'/config.php');
```

`__DIR__` is a '[magical constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)' and returns the directory of the current file without the trailing slash. It's actually an absolute path, you just have to concatenate the file name to `__DIR__`. In this case, as we need to ascend a directory we use PHP's `dirname` which ascends the file tree, and from here we can access `config.php`.

You could set the root path in this method too:

```
define('ROOT_PATH', dirname(__DIR__) . '/');
```

in test.php would set your root to be at the `/root/` level.

```
include(ROOT_PATH.'config.php');
```

Should then work to include the config file from where you want.

Comment: If you plan to use these constants with relative paths (i.e. `../`), I would encourage you to clean it up with `realpath()` before the `define()`.

Comment: Instead of using `ROOT_PATH.'../'`, I would use `dirname(ROOT_PATH)`. The latter would give you a "more absolute" path.

Comment: I have started a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Comment: You should consider that in windows dirname(__DIR__) get directory but with windows slash, so this method will just work with linux systems

Comment: so with this (your answer), we use absolute path instead of relative, right?

Comment: I think include(\_\_DIR\_\_."/../config.php"); looks much better.

Answer (score 1):

While I appreciate you believe absolute paths is not an option, it *is* a better option than relative paths and updating the PHP include path.

Use absolute paths with an constant you can set based on environment.

```
if (is_production()) {
    define('ROOT_PATH', '/some/production/path');
}
else {
    define('ROOT_PATH', '/root');
}

include ROOT_PATH . '/connect.php';
```

As commented, `ROOT_PATH` could also be derived from the current path, `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, etc.

Comment: `define('ROOT_PATH', __DIR__.'/../');`, perhaps?

Comment: This is definitely a good suggestion, and certainly works - but __DIR__ is more what I'm looking for. (I'm not the downvoter)

Comment: I have started a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507