# ../ on URL on php not working

Tags: php, html, url

this is kind of a silly question, but as I can't sort it out I thought it might be good to get some help. The point is that the ".. /" to go back directory is not working.

The file I'm executing is in a folder that's on the main route and I need to go back to the main route and then enter another folder to load this other PHP file but it's not working what could be causing this issue.

**ERRORS:**

> Warning: require_once(../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in things/public_html/classes/Mail.php on line 3
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php71/usr/share/pear') in things/public_html/classes/Mail.php on line 3

**DIRECTORY STRUCTURE:**

File where the requiere once is:

> /public_html/classes/filethatwantstoacces.php

File where it wants to get:

> /public_html/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php

```
require_once('../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
```

Comment: Can you show a diagram of your directory structure, showing where the main script and `PHPMailerAutoload.php` script are?

Comment: @Barmar added!.

Comment: I can't see any reason why it wouldn't work... can you post the full code of the file. Also, what error are you getting?

Comment: If, for some reason, upwards traversing doesn't work, you could try just doing `/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php`- ie, just going from root folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should be using is the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` variable. Please read [**this answer to another question**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43397154/3536236) for details.

> If you are using PHP you should get into a habit of **NOT** using relative file paths *at all* but to use absolute paths, which will guarentee to succeed every time (As long as the target file exists and is reachable, etc.).
>
> so; use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`
>
> As a side note, you **do not** need to use brackets for your `include`s/`require`s, it's simply giving the server more work to do for no extra benefit.
>
> The `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is the base directory of your PHP/web application, typically the contents of the folder `/public_html`.

Using correct syntax and the above `$_SERVER` value (which will point to the */public_html* folder you will have:

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
```

This will work from any script within your directory structure, if the file (PHPMailerAutoload.php) exists and is reachable at that given location

Answer (score 0):

Given your location

```
/public_html/classes/filethatwantstoacces.php
```

doing `../` gives you

```
/public_html/classes
```

so `../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php` evaluates to

```
/public_html/classes/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php
```

As [@Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3536236/martin) has pointed out, using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to construct an absolute path to your file is the easiest way to avoid relative directory navigation errors such as this:

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
```