# Best practice for URLs in included PHP files

Tags: php

Until now, I used to put absolute URLs in my included PHP files. For example in navbar.php, with a link to the services page: `href="http://domain.com/services.php"`

Since navbar.php is included in different directories, I had to use an absolute URL.

Problem is that when I'm testing the site locally using wamp server, this points me to the live site, which is not what I want.

What is the best practice for URLs in included PHP files?

I'm looking for something like 'root/thefile.php', where root can be either the domain (when the site is live) or localhost (when building and testing the site locally).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php SERVER_NAME should help you

Comment: or relative paths work too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407664/php-include-relative-path

Comment: That is not even an "absolute URL" you used before. URLs are _always_ absolute per definition, but yours is just a string that _might_ be interpreted as the combination of a hostname and a path. It lacks the scheme (protocol) that is mandatory for a URL.

Comment: A `path` usually is a better alternative, and typically one should prefer relative paths, since they allow flexibility in hierarchy, so it makes your code more portable.

Comment: Ah, I see you changed the "URL" you posted to a valid version ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
```

This will give you the root url ex.(domain.com)

So you could do use this:

```
echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST"];
```

And this would give you your url. You could also use

```
echo 'http://' . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
```

This will give you the complete url with the requests in it. ex (domain.com/thefile.php);

Comment: Which is quite an effort to create a URL if a path would be perfectly sufficient and more flexible.

Comment: `HTTP_HOST` is set by the client and should be avoided if possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
include ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/file path");
```