# The right file directory using define() functions

Tags: php

Im making a website with OpenCart. I have used Xampp but now it's done, and want to transfer it to my website, however i have this problem with local files:

This config.php file has used my local filenames, it's location:

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/webshop/admin/config.php
```

The config file contains these directions using the define function:

```
define('DIR_APPLICATION', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/webshop/admin/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/webshop/system/');
etc;
```

These variables are being called in files in other directories. 
I want to make a generalised config file, so no matter where the files calling are located from it works, but have no idea how. Thank you!

Comment: why not simply changing them to relative paths like `./` and `../system/`?

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407664/php-include-relative-path