# PHP include path Server 500 Error

Tags: php

I'm having very confusing problems with a basic php include.

I'm currently working on a version 2 of a website, so my index.php is located in

```
www.mywebsite.co.uk/v2/index.php
```

I have a database config file located inside

```
www.mywebsite.co.uk/v2/assets/database.php
```

I have a form action located inside

```
www.mywebsite.co.uk/v2/assets/actions/action.php
```

I need to include my database.php file inside my action.php file, but I cant seem to find the right include path.

I've tried

```
include "database.php";
include "assets/database.php";
include "../assets/database.php";
include "../../assets/database.php";
include "../database.php";
include "../../database.php";
include "../../../database.php";
include "../../../assets/database.php";
```

I've even started using

```
include(dirname(__FILE__)."../database.php");
```

But no matter what i try, the include file cannot be found, and my action page returns a 500 server error.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I'm having the weirdest issue, and I really cant figure out whats going on.

I am including all my files normally, and they all work great, but as soon as it comes to a form action file, include just refuses to work.

I'm including a database OOP file in my header across the site, and it works great. I then have a form which submits using POST to an action file, and as soon as I include the database in my action file, it refuses to work. It will only work if I use

```
dirname(__FILE__)."my/path"
```

The location of the action file is in the same folder as all my other files which are using the include function, so the path is definitely correct, but whenever i try to include on my action file I get a 500 server error unless i use the dirname(**FILE**)."my/path" method.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE 2**

For some reason I have to use a different include path for 2 different files both in the same location.

For example database.php, home-slider.php  and includes.php are all in the same directory. If I want database.php to access the includes file I can use

```
include "assets/includes.php";
```

But if i want to access the includes file using the home-slider.php page I have to use

```
include "../assets/includes.php";
```

Even though they are all in the same directory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP include relative path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407664/php-include-relative-path)

Comment: Using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path/to/file'` works a lot better than trying to figure out relative paths.

Comment: I would recomond you that you use this:`require_once('../../database.php');`

Comment: That one did work. Can I ask, why do I have to use the dirname() function? I'm aware of what the function does, but I thought include used the current file location as a reference, so just  include "../../database.php"; but instead I have to use 
     include(dirname(__FILE__)."../../database.php");

Comment: have you modified your `.htaccess` file or Apache's virtual host configs at all? im wondering if you are somehow redirecting.

Comment: @CodeGodie never use `include`, always use `require_once`, have a look at the official documentation

Comment: @matiaslauriti Can you explain why in your own words?

Comment: @CodeGodie I tagged you and not @Sam, sorry !! Don't use `include` (if you are not returning anything from the file) and use `require_once` because `include` will TRY TO include the file, if it is not found, you will not get an exception and code will continue execution until an exception is thrown because that file functionality was not included. If you use `require_once` it will throw an exception if not found AND will only require it once if it was already required.

Comment: @matiaslauriti no problem. Though I would NOT say _"never use include"_, there are occasions where you would want to use it. Its really up to the dev and the application wether you want to require it or not.

Comment: @CodeGodie yes, I am really used to use OOP, so I use `namespace`s and just `require_once` the class by autoloading.

Comment: @matiaslauriti yes i agree with that, namespaces are the way to go

Answer (score 0):

If this is your file structure:

```
v2/
|
|-- assets/
|      |
|      |-- actions/
|      |      |
|      |      |-- action.php
|      |
|      |-- database.php
|
|-- index.php
```

Then by adding `include '../database.php'` on `action.php` should work. if it is not, then you might have something wrong your PHP file. You may also use `require  '../database.php';` to see what errors that gives you as it will throw errors regarding database.php.

Comment: i'm getting 2 errors on my page

Warning: include(assets/includes.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in mydirectory\v3\assets\home-slider.php on line 3

and

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'assets/includes.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;.\includes;.\pear') in mydirectory\v3\assets\home-slider.php on line 3

Comment: the file does exist in that directory just to clarify, so I don't know why im getting that error.

Comment: is the file structure correct? I updated my answer.. doesnt make sense why you keep getting that error.

Comment: Also, the error points to `assets/includes.php` thats a different file than the ones you mentioned.

Comment: That is my file structure, but I have to use `../../database.php` in my action file. Almost like I have to navigate outside of the assets folder before I can navigate back into it.