# php require_once issue require_once

Tags: php

I currently have a file `class.main.php` here:
`app/main/class/class.main.php`

`session.php` is located in `app/main/session.php`

`class.user.php` is located in `app/main/class/class.user.php`

The first few lines of `class.main.php` include:

```
require_once("../../session.php");
require_once("../../../class.user.php");
```

The statements do not seem to work, I feel like it is a problem with the `../../`

How can I correctly require these files when they're in different directories?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP include relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407664/php-include-relative-path)

Answer (score 0):

`realpath()` expands all symbolic links and resolves references to /./, /../ and extra / characters in the input path and returns the canonicalized absolute pathname.

Referrer : http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

**Example**

```
require_once realpath('.').'/yourfolder/session.php';
```

`realpath('.')` returns the main index.

Output :

> /myhttpdfolder

Answer (score -1):

```
require_once("../session.php");
require_once("class.user.php");
```

As class.user.php is in the same folder you can access it directly be name and session.php is in main folder so you can access it like i mentioned above.

I hope it works for you!