# php relative path fails

Tags: php, centos

I have been setting up a new web server to replace an aging one and I am having some problems with relative paths that work on the existing server.
The existing server is Centos 6 with php 5.6, however the new server is Centos 7 with the same php version. I should also mention that both servers run WHM/cPanel with a single user (solo) licence.

I have several folders one level above the `public_html` folder that contain some include files and also some php files that are run from cron jobs. I put these here as there is never any need for them in the `public_html` folder.

```
// Example folder structure
-includes
-cjobs
-public_html
   -includes
   -css
   -js
   index.php
```

On the existing server, the following works ok on a file in the `cjobs` folder 
`include "../public_html/includes/mail_include.php";`, however on the new server it fails. I have ended up using `include_once (dirname(__FILE__) . "/../includes/mail_include.php");` and also had to relocate the `cjobs` folder into the `public_html` folder. Note that full paths do work ok, so `/home/username/includes/mail_include.php` does always work, but I don't want to hard code the paths.

I feel that there may be some small configuration setting in php that I have not changed, but I just have not been able to figure out why I need to include the files this way. It means I need to modify thousands of files just so they will work on the new server which is proving to be a real pain.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP include relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407664/php-include-relative-path)

Comment: If you do: `include __DIR__ . '/../includes/foo.php`, (the same as dirname(__FILE__)) it's not the same as "hard code the paths". What that does is to append the absolute path to the current file. This is recommended to do since using just a relative path can break things if you include this file in another file (since the include will then be from the top most PHP file and not from where the `include` is written).