# My require_once has a right path but doesn't work

Tags: php

This is what my directory looks like:

```
>admin
  >scripts
     file.php
>config
  database.php
```

I'm trying to use

```
require_once '../config/database.php';
```

on the file.php, but it doesn't seem to be able to find said file. Gives me the error

> Warning: require_once(../load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:/path_to_file.php

Comment: load.php is not listed in your question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP include relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407664/php-include-relative-path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require_once '../../config/database.php';
```

Try this. I think you have to go backwards twice :)