# function from header include not accessible in other (sub) includes

Tags: php

I have a `header.php` & `footer.php` in a directory called `templates` and `index.php` & `example.php` in the root directory.

```
- index.php
- example.php
- templates
    - header.php
    - footer.php
```

Inside the `example.php` file, there is a function:

**example.php**

```
<?php
  function someFunction() {
    return "Hello World";
  }
?>
```

I included `example.php` in my `header.php` file and included `header.php` in my `index.php` file as follows:

**header.php**

```
<?php include '../example.php'; ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><?php echo someFunction(); ?></h1>
```

**footer.php**

```
  </body>
<html>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php include 'templates/header.php'; ?>
<div>
  <h2><?php echo someFunction(); ?></h2>
</div>
<?php include 'templates/footer.php'; ?>
```

The function `someFunction()` works fine in `header.php` and the echo returns `Hello World` but the same function is not available in `index.php` and returns nothing. What is the right way to go about this?

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17407995/13720553 answer your question?

Comment: @schmauch That approach would mean I have to add an `include` for the `example.php` file in all pages that need `someFunction()` even though `header.php` is already included in all those same pages. I'm trying to find a way to access a function that is included in a page (here, `header.php`) that is included in the current page (here, `index.php`).

Comment: In other words, I'm trying to access a function in `example.php` via `header.php` in `index.php`.

Comment: No, it means, you should work with absolute paths. To do so, you could use `realpath(__DIR__.'../example.php')` in `header.php`

Comment: Little mistake: I forgot a slash. `realpath(__DIR__.'/../example.php')` is correct.

Comment: @schmauch I think you're misunderstanding my question. The above helps with path issues when including say, `example.php` in say, `header.php`. I'm talking about accessing a function included in `header.php` from say, `index.php` which included `header.php`. Including `example.php` in `header.php` with proper paths which your example as well as the dupe you linked are talking about is something I have already figured out and it's working fine.

Comment: Do you have set `display_errors = On` in your php.ini file? Otherwise you won't see any errors. And the error message says, that `../example.php` can't be included in `header.php`. So you won't see anything because php stops execution. Follow my advice and include correctly and you'll see, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Let's put my comments into an answer:

When you call `index.php` your current work directory is the root directory. Including `templates/header.php` works fine. But the `include '../example.php` in `header.php` fails because it searches for `example.php` in the parent directory of your root directory. This leads to a fatal error and php stops execution.

Using `include realpath(__DIR__.'/../example.php')` in `header.php` will solve your problem.

Comment: `example.php` is including fine in `header.php` and any variable/function defined in `example.php` can be echoed/accessed in `header.php`. But when I try to echo the same thing on any page that includes `header.php`, it doesn't work regardless of using `realpath()` or not.