# How to include a file from "root"?

Tags: php

(This has amost certinaly been anwsered before, but I can't find it here...)
I've been banging my head against the wall for far to long now, this should not be as complicated as I seem to find it...

File structure:
.

./v1

./v2

./v2/index.php

./v2/Conn/dbopen.php

./v2/inc/functions/logit.php

./v2/inc/function/special_function/dosomething.php

I need to find some way of including `"./v2/Conn/dbopen.php"` from "where ever".
If, in `"logit.php"`, I enter: `require "../../Conn/dbopen.php";` that won't work when I call `logit()` from logit.php in dosomething.php since then the path won't be right.

I'm not allowed to include it with the full URL (`http*://www.example.com/v2/Conn/dbopen.php`).

To make it a bit more complex (?), it needs to work for serveral server with different folder structure.
`http://localhost/site/, https://www.test.example.com/, https://www.example.com`

I've tried with all sorts of solutions I can come up with.
`$_SERVER-variables`, full URL-includes and all other ways I can think of.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP include relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407664/php-include-relative-path)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are doing vanilla PHP:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
// The document root directory under which the current script
// is executing, as defined in the server's configuration file.
```

Use a boot file. Create a boot.php and include it at the top of every php file.

*boot.php*

```
<?php
// Put this in root dir of site
define('ROOT', __DIR__);
// make a convenience function
function root_path($path)
{
    return ROOT . $path;
}
```

Some other php

```
<?php
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/boot.php";
// Now we can write code that is more readable.
require_once root_path('/some/dir/file.php');
```

Comment: Thanks, that should have worked, it looks like right way to go.

I've created the boot.php in the "root" of the site (/v2/boot.php) exatcly like you described above.
I've created a test-file in /v2/test/testpath.php and at the top: 'require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/sitename/v2/boot.php";'.
It seem to work, when I step the code it don't fail.

But when I try 'require_once root_path('/Connections/opendb.php');' I get:
'"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function root_path()' in C:\xampp\htdocs\sitename\v2\test\testpath.php:3"'.

It looks good to me, but..

Comment: It seems like you have not solved this. Or maybe you did. The way you are using this means that DOCUMENT_ROOT is the /v2 directory. "root of the site" is vague. It looks like the Apache DOCUMENT_ROOT is the parent directory of /v2, not v2 itself according to the sample URL you provided.